# Django Tastypie Basic Authentication not working

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have a UserResource class that allows a person to make API calls against a User object. When I try to authenticate with BasicAuthentication it tells me access is denied. I am using a username and password that should be able to access an object. Any ideas why BasicAuthentication may not be working for me?

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        # For authentication, allow both basic and api key so that the key
        # can be grabbed, if needed.
        authentication = MultiAuthentication(
            BasicAuthentication(),
            ApiKeyAuthentication())
        authorization = Authorization()
        resource_name = 'user'

        allowed_methods = ['get', 'patch', 'put', ]
        always_return_data = True
        queryset = User.objects.all().select_related("api_key")
        excludes = ['is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'date_joined',
                'last_login']

    def authorized_read_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        return object_list.filter(id=bundle.request.user.id).select_related()

    def hydrate(self, bundle):
        if "raw_password" in bundle.data:
            raw_password = bundle.data["raw_password"]

        # Validate password
            if not validate_password(raw_password):
                if len(raw_password) < MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH:
                    raise CustomBadRequest(
                        code="invalid_password",
                        message=(
                            "Your password should contain at least {length} "
                            "characters.".format(length=
                                                 MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH)))
                raise CustomBadRequest(
                    code="invalid_password",
                    message=("Your password should contain at least one number"
                             ", one uppercase letter, one special character,"
                             " and no spaces."))

            bundle.data["password"] = make_password(raw_password)

        return bundle

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        bundle.data['key'] = bundle.obj.api_key.key
        # Don't return `raw_password` in response.
        del bundle.data["password"]
        return bundle
```

Here is the unit test line that is coming back as not authenticated:

```
 resp = self.api_client.get('/api/v1/user/2/', format='json', HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Basic ' + base64.b64encode('johndoe:j0hnd03'))
```

I know that "johndoe" and "j0hnd03" are the correct username and password. If I use the ApiKey method for that user it works fine.

I have also tried the following:

```
resp = self.api_client.get('/api/v1/user/2/', format='json', authentication=self.create_basic(username='johndoe', password='j0hnd03'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I believe that the matter could be in your exclude :
 excludes = ['is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'date_joined',
            'last_login']
try to restrict the exclude field to see what you will get, depending of the users type.
```

Comment: I removed the excludes and that did not change anything. I am still getting a 401 status. ApiKey works so it doesn't make sense why BasicAuthentication doesn't work.